# Class Library for local dataBase(mdb)

Tags: c#, ms-access, dataset, oledbdataadapter

Two projects that will interact (CRUD) with a local database (mdb). How to implement this? DataSet, OleDbDataAdapter-s, connectionString. Where it all to create. Explain please. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for [Creating an N-Tier Data Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384570.aspx)

And here - [Understand 3- Tier Architecture in C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/662107/Understand-Tier-Architecture-in-Csharp)

Links

1) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384570.aspx

2) https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/662107/Understand-Tier-Architecture-in-Csharp

3) [Working With DataSet in ADO.NET](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/718fc8/working-with-dataset-in-ado-net/)

Comment: Could you give a link to this type of solution (example)?

Comment: I'm not stupid;))do you think do I need such an option? I have a simple database which will work two projects. I need dataset, dataadapter's for this database. thank's.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that you didn't see links, I added one link more

Comment: I am so embarassed, sorry